# What am I doing wrong with this long-to-wide reshape?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data.table, reshape

### the problem

A function I wrote to widen a long table of repeated multivariate time series data for input to classifier functions seems to cause erroneous results even for easy test data, but I can't locate the issue.

### background

I am keeping a bunch of repeated trials of multivariate time series in a long data.table format like this, for speed and ease of use with most R idioms:

```
> this.data
              Time Trial Class Channel      Value
     1: -100.00000     1    -1      V1  0.4551513
     2:  -96.07843     2    -1      V1  0.8241555
     3:  -92.15686     3    -1      V1  0.7667328
     4:  -88.23529     4    -1      V1  0.7475106
     5:  -84.31373     5    -1      V1  0.9810273
    ---                                          
204796:  884.31373   196     1      V4 50.2642220
204797:  888.23529   197     1      V4 50.5747661
204798:  892.15686   198     1      V4 50.5749421
204799:  896.07843   199     1      V4 50.1988299
204800:  900.00000   200     1      V4 50.7756015
```

Specifically, the above data has a `Time` column with 256 unique numbers from 0 to 900, which is repeated for each `Channel`, for each `Trial`. Similarly, each `Channel` is one of `V1,V2,V3,V4`, repeated for each `Time` sample, for each `Trial`. In other words, any combination of `Time,Trial,Channel` uniquely specifies a `Value`. In order to keep things simple, all `Trial`s under 100 have `Class` -1, and all above 99 have `Class` 1. (For testing purposes, all `Value`s in `Class` 1 have a mean of 50, while those in `Class` 0 have a mean of 0. (This data can be generated and tweaked using the `dummy.plug()` function included in [a gist I made](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0ff510ec5e6dbaaeaf4c).)

In order to process the data using different machine learning classification algorithms, it seems to be necessary to reshape the data to something a little bit wider, so that each of the time series has its own column, while the others remain as ids. (For example, the stepwise classifier `stepclass` from `klaR` needs the features in different columns, so it can choose which ones to drop or add to its model as it trains.) Since there are repeated trials, I have not had success making existing functions like the `cast` family work, and so I wrote my own:

```
##### converting from long table form to channel-split wide form #####
# for multivariate repeated time series
channel.form <- function(input.table,
                         value.col = "Voltage",
                         split.col = "Channel",
                         class.col = "Class",
                         time.col = "Time",
                         trial.col = "Trial") {
# Converts long table format to slightly wider format split by channels.
# For epoched datasets.

  setkeyv(input.table, class.col)

  chan.split <- split(input.table,input.table[,get(split.col)])

  chan.d <- cbind(lapply(chan.split, function(x){
    x[,value.col,with=FALSE]}))

  chan.d <- as.data.table(matrix(unlist(chan.d),
                            ncol = input.table[,length(unique(get(split.col)))], 
                            byrow=TRUE))

  # reintroduce class labels
  # since the split is over identical sections for each channel, we can just use
  # the first split's labels
  chan.d <- chan.d[,c(class.col):= chan.split[[1]][,get(class.col)]]
  chan.d[,c(class.col):=as.factor(get(class.col))]

  # similarly with time and trial labels
  chan.d <- chan.d[,Time:= chan.split[[1]][,get(time.col)]]
  chan.d <- chan.d[,Trial:= chan.split[[1]][,get(trial.col)]]

  return(chan.d) 
}
```

Using this function, I take some multivariate trials that I have prepared into a long `data.table` like the one at the top, and reshape them into a wider one that looks like this:

```
> this.data.training.channel
              V1        V2        V3        V4 Class       Time Trial
    1: -50.58389 -50.56397 -50.74251 -50.86700    -1 -100.00000     1
    2: -50.92713 -50.28009 -50.15078 -50.70161    -1  -96.07843     2
    3: -50.84276 -50.02456 -50.20015 -50.45228    -1  -76.47059     7
    4: -50.68679 -50.05475 -50.04270 -50.83900    -1  -72.54902     8
    5: -50.55954 -50.88998 -50.01273 -50.86856    -1  -68.62745     9
   ---                                                               
35836:  49.52361  49.37465  49.73997  49.10543     1  876.47059   194
35837:  49.93162  49.38352  49.62406  49.16854     1  888.23529   197
35838:  49.67510  49.63853  49.54259  49.81198     1  892.15686   198
35839:  49.26295  49.98449  49.60437  49.03918     1  896.07843   199
35840:  49.05030  49.42035  49.48546  49.73438     1  900.00000   200
```

At this point, I take the widened table and give it to a classifier like `lda()`, then test it on a separate random portion of the same data:

```
lda.model <- lda(Class ~ . -Trial, this.data.training.channel)
lda.pred <- predict(lda.model, this.data.testing.channel)
```

### symptoms

However, even if I generate obscenely separated dummy data (see picture below), I am getting near-chance results with existing reasonable libraries. (I know the libraries are probably not at fault, because if I allow the algorithm to use the trial index as a training feature, it correctly classifies every input.)

[image: hugely separated two-class data in four channels]

```
> table(predicted = lda.pred$class, data = this.data.testing.channel[,Class])
         data
predicted   -1    1
       -1 2119 1878
       1  5817 5546

> 1-sum(lda.pred$class != this.data.testing.channel[,Class])/length(lda.pred$class)
[1] 0.4984375

> table(predicted = sda.pred$class, data = this.data.testing.channel[,Class])
         data
predicted   -1    1
       -1 3705 3969
       1  3719 3967

> 1-sum(sda.pred$class != this.data.testing.channel[,Class])/length(sda.pred$class)
[1] 0.4994792
```

The error rate is basically a coin flip, despite the values from class `1` being about 50 times the values from class `-1`. I have to be making some huge mistake (which I think is a programming one, otherwise I would be over on cross validated), but I have spent days prodding it and rewriting code with no improvement. (As an example, note that I get the same result whether or not I scale the input values so that they have mean 0, variance 1.)

### reproducing the problem

A complete gist that can be run to reproduce the problem is available [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0ff510ec5e6dbaaeaf4c).

### possible problems I considered, what I tried

(see previous revisions of the question for the full list, due to length considerations)

I wrote a function (included in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0ff510ec5e6dbaaeaf4c)) to generate easily separable dummy data, and wrote another function to average each of the two classes, faceted by `Channel` and colored by `Class`, like the plot above. Playing with each of the parameters (difference in population means, channel count, etc.) seems to produce expected output, as well as peeking at appropriate subsets using calls like `this.data[Trial==1,unique(Time),by=Subject]`.

### what do I need to solve this?

I would greatly appreciate any advice on fixing this. I just can't see what I'm doing wrong.

If someone either diagnosed/located the issue, or was able to illustrate, using a different approach, a reshaped table from the data that worked with these (popular) classifier functions, I wouldn't just accept, I would award a bounty (after testing, of course).

#### session info

```
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[9] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] doMC_1.3.2              iterators_1.0.6         AUC_0.3.0              
 [4] LiblineaR_1.80-7        RcppRoll_0.1.0          RcppArmadillo_0.4.300.0
 [7] Rcpp_0.11.1             foreach_1.4.1           cvTools_0.3.2          
[10] robustbase_0.90-2       latticist_0.9-44        vcd_1.3-1              
[13] latticeExtra_0.6-26     lattice_0.20-29         pheatmap_0.7.7         
[16] RColorBrewer_1.0-5      klaR_0.6-10             MASS_7.3-29            
[19] ggplot2_0.9.3.1         reshape2_1.2.2          data.table_1.9.2       
[22] sda_1.3.3               fdrtool_1.2.12          corpcor_1.6.6          
[25] entropy_1.2.0           zoo_1.7-11              testthat_0.8           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] codetools_0.2-8  colorspace_1.2-4 combinat_0.0-8   compiler_3.0.2   DEoptimR_1.0-1  
 [6] dichromat_2.0-0  digest_0.6.4     gtable_0.1.2     gWidgets_0.0-52  labeling_0.2    
[11] munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8         proto_0.3-10     scales_0.2.3     stringr_0.6.2   
[16] tools_3.0.2
```

Comment: It's rather unclear how you assign the same "class, time, trial" to all of your different "channel" values.  I strongly suggest if you can't, as you wrote, get `cast` to do what you want, that you learn how to use `cast` correctly, or investigate general subsetting (or `aggregate` -type) functions.  If you could post a small, reproducible example to justify your assignment of data to all four `Channel` values, as well as validating your claims of classification failure, that would help too.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft To be honest, I was concerned about burying the question in code, so I left most of it to the gist (which includes a moderate amount of comments in the code). I don't believe that `cast` can be used to solve this on its own (after spending a few days on it), because the combination of channel/trial/time uniquely specifies a data point, leading to `NA`s everywhere with sparsely placed values (at least however I tried it with `cast`). I'm not aggregating either (I think). Could you explain more about what you mean by "justify your assignment of data to all four `Channel` values"?

Comment: What I can't see from the sample of your original dataset is whether or how often  your variables `Time` `trial` and `value` are repeated, and how you are intending to re-organize or re-group the data.

Comment: Got it. I edited to explain that further. Close voters, I have essentially unlimited willingness to make this question answerable, so be constructive and tell me what you need ;)

Comment: I admire your patience at dealing with both R and Stackoverflow... tip: try to make your question more precise and specific. If you have multiple issues, divide them on different questions. In your code, go from simple to complex. And most important, if at risk of dying from an R overdose remember there is Python and C++ out there...

Comment: I appreciate that a lot! I wish I *could* narrow the question down; that would probably be a big part of the solution.

Comment: make your question be self-contained and fit on a single page - if you can't that means you haven't spent enough effort and are hoping someone else will do it for you (hint: not super likely to happen)

Comment: Is the gist not self-contained enough? Sure there is a bit of code, but most of that is functions to simplify the explanation. I'll tighten the question up, though.

Comment: Could you also post your `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for being a good sport and offering comments. I think I will come back to this question when the time comes to clean up the fixes I put in my own code, and make sure this one is just as clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not reproduce your error and I found some problems with `dummy.plug()`. I generated data with

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
library("MASS")

set.seed(115)
pp<-dummy.plug(trial.count = 200,
    chan.count = 4,
    mean.diff = 100,
    value.name = "Value")
```

And I don't care for data.table so i just converted it to a basic data.frame.

```
dd<-as.data.frame(pp)
```

Now you say that `Time`, `Trial`, and `Channel` should uniquely identify a value, but that does not seem to be the case in the dummy data. I see that

```
subset(dd, Time==-100 & Trial==1 & Channel=="V1")

#       Time Trial Class Channel      Value
# 1     -100     1    -1      V1 0.73642916
# 6401  -100     1    -1      V1 0.17648939
# 12801 -100     1    -1      V1 0.41366964
# 19201 -100     1    -1      V1 0.07044473
# 25601 -100     1    -1      V1 0.86583284
# 32001 -100     1    -1      V1 0.24255411
# 38401 -100     1    -1      V1 0.92473225
# 44801 -100     1    -1      V1 0.69989600
```

So there are clearly multiple values for each combination. So to proceed, I decided just to take the mean of the observed values. I had no problems using `dcast` with

```
xx<-dcast(dd, Class+Time+Trial~Channel, fun.aggregate=mean)
```

Then I split up the training/test datasets

```
train.trials = sample(unique(dd$Trial), 140)
train.data = subset(xx, Trial %in% train.trials)
test.data = subset(xx, !Trial %in% train.trials)
```

Then I ran lda as above

```
lda.model <- lda(Class ~ . -Trial, train.data)
lda.pred <- predict(lda.model, test.data)
```

And I checked out how I did

```
table(lda.pred$class, test.data$Class)
#        -1    1
#   -1  704    0
#   1     0 1216
```

And I appear to do much better than you did.

Unless something bad happened when i converted the data.table to a data.frame, there seems to be problems with your test data. Perhaps there is a problem with your non-cast reshape function. Seeing as how `dcast` works just fine, maybe you want to check that your function works as well.

Comment: This turned out to be both the answer to the question *and* the answer I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MrFlick was right on both counts. For the sake of completeness, here is a `data.table` answer with some extra explanation.

### bad dummy data function

The dummy function in the above gist was indeed bad; the crucial lines are these:

```
  dummy.data <- data.table(matrix(runif(length(time.vector)*trial.count*chan.count),
                                  ncol=chan.count),
                           Time=rep(time.vector,times = trial.count))
  setkey(dummy.data,Time)
  dummy.data <- dummy.data[,Trial:=seq_len(trial.count)]
```

Since `Trial` will be recycled down the table once set, every other column has to match the same permutation (wrap over `Trial` values). A fast way to do this is sorting by `Time`, which is one of the effects of `setkey()`. Once this is done, the data can indeed be uniquely sorted:

```
# load dummy data
set.seed(115)
this.data <- dummy.plug(trial.count = 200,
                       chan.count = 4,
                       mean.diff = 50,
                       value.name = "Value")
> this.data[(Trial==1 & Channel=="V1" & Time == -100),]
   Time Trial Class Channel     Value
1: -100     1    -1      V1 0.7364292
```

### dcast works now

Now that the uniqueness criterion is satisfied, `dcast` works on the data table:

```
> this.data.channel <- dcast.data.table(this.data,
+                                                Class+Time+Trial~Channel,
+                                                fun.aggregate=identity)
Using 'Value' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
> this.data.channel
       Class Time Trial           V1         V2         V3          V4
    1:    -1 -100     1 7.364292e-01  0.8889176  0.4638730  0.61258621
    2:    -1 -100     2 9.030099e-02  0.1435559  0.1596734  0.88577669
    3:    -1 -100     3 6.685920e-01  0.1013146  0.7156151  0.51144831
    4:    -1 -100     4 9.154142e-04  0.2429634  0.3169072  0.05810808
    5:    -1 -100     5 7.383397e-01  0.3668977  0.3779892  0.34938949
   ---                                                                
51196:     1  900   196 5.028103e+01 50.2810276 50.2810276 50.28102761
51197:     1  900   197 5.080229e+01 50.8022872 50.8022872 50.80228716
51198:     1  900   198 5.084255e+01 50.8425466 50.8425466 50.84254662
51199:     1  900   199 5.096859e+01 50.9685913 50.9685913 50.96859133
51200:     1  900   200 5.034459e+01 50.3445878 50.3445878 50.34458784
```

You can quickly spot check to see that this worked properly:

```
> this.data.channel[,unique(Trial),by=Class]
     Class  V1
  1:    -1   1
  2:    -1   2
  3:    -1   3
  4:    -1   4
  5:    -1   5
 ---          
196:     1 196
197:     1 197
198:     1 198
199:     1 199
200:     1 200
```

### classification check

The remainder of the gist works, as does MrFlick's snippet.

```
> lda.model <- lda(Class ~ . -Trial, this.data.training.channel)
> lda.pred <- predict(lda.model, this.data.testing.channel)
> table(predicted = lda.pred$class, data = this.data.testing.channel[,Class])
         data
predicted   -1    1
       -1 5888    0
       1     0 9472
> 1-sum(lda.pred$class != this.data.testing.channel[,Class])/length(lda.pred$class)
[1] 1
```

Why I couldn't get `dcast` working before is something I will have to dig into an old revision to look at. I suspect a permutation problem (during import instead of generation) like the above contributed to it.

Comment: +1 for the completeness. Definitely a sigh of relief to know it's not a bug with `dcast.data.table` ;).

Comment: I am definitely scared to look under the hood of that one. I have nightmares about permutation problems as it is.